# Java Comparator for byte array (lexicographic)

Tags: java, sorting, collections, dictionary, compare

I have a hashmap with byte[] keys. I'd like to sort it through a TreeMap.

What is the most effective way to implement the comparator for lexicographic order?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), you can use either of:

- [UnsignedBytes.lexicographicalComparator()](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html#lexicographicalComparator%28%29)
- [SignedBytes.lexicographicalComparator()](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/SignedBytes.html#lexicographicalComparator%28%29)

The `UnsignedBytes` comparator appears to have an optimized form using `Unsafe` that it uses if it can. Comments in the code indicate that it may be at least twice as fast as a normal Java implementation.

Comment: do we have the solution in "Java",if so please post a working example.

Comment: As ColinD says in the comment to my answer, my solution is the same as the non optimized one in Guava. So you can straight use mine, which is a working example, or follow ColinD's links.

Answer (score 20):

Found this nice piece of code in Apache Hbase:

```
    public int compare(byte[] left, byte[] right) {
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < left.length && j < right.length; i++, j++) {
            int a = (left[i] & 0xff);
            int b = (right[j] & 0xff);
            if (a != b) {
                return a - b;
            }
        }
        return left.length - right.length;
    }
```

Comment: This is basically what the non-optimized version of Guava's `UnsignedBytes.lexicographicalComparator()` does.

Comment: Hmm, why did they use `i` and `j`, when one variable would've been sufficient. Also, storing `int length = Math.min(left.length, right.length)` and comparing `i < length` would improve this for large arrays

Comment: you would expect that the length field of the array would be as expensive

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming the problem is just with the "byte vs. byte" comparison.  Dealing with the arrays is straightforward, so I won't cover it.  With respect to byte vs. byte, my first thought is to do this:

```
public class ByteComparator implements Comparator<byte> {
  public int compare(byte b1, byte b2) {
    return new Byte(b1).compareTo(b2);
  }
}
```

But that won't be lexicographic:  0xFF (the signed byte for -1) will be considered smaller than 0x00, when lexicographically it's bigger.  I think this should do the trick:

```
public class ByteComparator implements Comparator<byte> {
  public int compare(byte b1, byte b2) {
    // convert to unsigned bytes (0 to 255) before comparing them.
    int i1 = b1 < 0 ? 256 + b1 : b1;
    int i2 = b2 < 0 ? 256 + b2 : b2;
    return i2 - i1;
  }
}
```

Probably there is something in Apache's commons-lang or commons-math libraries that does this, but I don't know it off hand.

Comment: There is Byte.comparator built into Java. No need to implement this.

Comment: @KenHuffman Java's Byte.comparator is not lexicographic in the way OP probably wants:  Java's built-in Byte.comparator considers byte value 255 to be smaller than byte value 0.