# Does Java String.getBytes("UTF-8") preserve lexicograhpical order?

Tags: java, sorting, utf-8, arrays, lexicographic

If I have a lexicographical sorted list of Java Strings `[s1,s2,s3,s4, ...., sn]`, and then convert each String into a byte array using UTF-8 encoding `bx = sx.getBytes("UTF-8")`, is the list of byte arrays `[b1,b2,b3,...bn]` also lexicographical sorted?

Comment: since UTF-8 is a variable width encoding, I would say that the sort order will not be preserved

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes any sense; how would you sort bits/bytes lexicographically? The character set you map those bits/bytes to is the determining factor.

Comment: @Brian Roach Lexicographical order on byte arrays is similar to that on Strings. Just replace "character at x" with "byte at x". See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108091/java-comparator-for-byte-array-lexicographic

Comment: @Dmitry Not necessarily. I do not need to compare all bytes, only until the first difference. Since UTF-8 is reversible the first difference in length for 2 characters should imply difference in bytes of their encoding. I'm however not sure this is enough to preserve order.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky: But UTF-8 was specifically designed to preserve sort order nevertheless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.** According to [RFC 3239](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt):

> The byte-value lexicographic sorting order of UTF-8 strings is the
>        same as if ordered by character numbers.  Of course this is of
>        limited interest since a sort order based on character numbers is
>        almost never culturally valid.

As Ian Roberts pointed out, this applies for "*true* UTF-8 (such as `String.getBytes` will give you)", but beware of [`DataInputStream`'s fake UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8), which will sort [U+000000] after [U+000001] and [U+00F000] after [U+10FFFF].

Comment: For completeness, note that this is correct for _true_ UTF-8 (such as `String.getBytes` will give you) but not necessarily for the "[modified UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8)" used by `DataInputStream` and friends.

Comment: @IanRoberts: Right. In fact modified UTF-8 sorts [U+000000] after [U+000001] and [U+00F000] after [U+10FFFF].

Comment: Are you sure this answer is correct? Isn't the normal Java lexicographical order for Strings based on UTF-16 rather than Unicode code points?

Answer (score -2):

You get a list/array of objects X, in a given orden.

You create a new list/array Y of such objects, applying a method.

Y will have the ordering that you created it with (normally you will have just kept X order). No reordering happens.

Also, lexycographical ordering for a byte[] is meaningless.

Comment: lexicographical ordering for a byte[] is not meaningless. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108091/java-comparator-for-byte-array-lexicographic