# Hbase use integer as row key and lexicographical order

Tags: java, hbase, lexicographic

I'm designing an Hbase schema where the row key should be an integer. I intend to use scan API from java with startrow and endrow with integer values.

I guess I can transform my integers in a String with `'0'` padding to respect the lexicographical order, but my keys will be much bigger than if I use the binary representation of an integer.

How can I transform my integer (let's say an `int`) in `byte[]` so that a scan will return the expected values if I use the same transformation for startrow and endrow ?

**Answer:**

Nils gave the anwser and I found a confirmation here:

[Java Comparator for byte array (lexicographic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108091/java-comparator-for-byte-array-lexicographic)

Hbase extracts `int` from `byte[]` and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes from the hbase-client library.

From byte-array to int:

```
Bytes.toInt(byteArray)
```

From int to byte-array:

```
Bytes.toBytes(intvalue)
```

I have actually made an online tool to generate the hex values I need to query row-ids in hbase shell [right here](https://nilsmagnus.github.io/bytearrays/).

Comment: Thanks Nils. If I use this transformaton for i1 and i2 I will obtain byte[] b1 and b2. If i1 < i2 then I will have b1 < b2 if I compare them lexicographically as Hbase will do to comapre keys during scan ?

Comment: I guess so. (the size of b1==b2, but the contents will be lexicographical comparable in the order you want)  But hbase will maintain the lexicographical order for you on new inserts/deletions, so you do not have to worry about this when scanning.